# Replace each value in array with new value (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, list

```
prefix = "!"    

commands = [
        "command_1",
        "command_2"]

commands.each do |command|
    command = prefix + command
end
```

This is pretty straightforward. I want to change the strings `"command_1"` & `"command_2"` to `"!command_1"` & `"!command_2"`. How would I do that?

Comment: The reason that this does not work is that [String#+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-2B) results in a new string. The old strings just keep sitting unaltered in the commands array. Choose `map` to store the new strings in a new array, or choose a method which mutates the strings, as the answers and comments indicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `map`

```
commands_with_prefix = commands.map { |command| prefix + command }
```

or `map!` to update the array in-place

```
commands.map! { |command| prefix + command }
```

another way, interpolation

```
commands.map! { |command| "#{prefix}#{command}" }
```

Comment: Or `String#replace` e.g. `commands.each {|c| c.replace("#{prefix}#{c}") }`

Comment: @steenslag that is much better although you could always `c.sub!(/\A/,prefix)` :)

Comment: @Tearzz `commands.each { |command| command.insert(0, prefix) }`

Comment: commands_with_prefix = commands.map { |command| "!" << command }    as + operator returns a new String each time while << on the other hand concatenates to the given object.

Comment: Thanks to everyone :)